# How can I prevent keyboard input but allow 3D Handheld Scanner Input?

Tags: vb.net

I need a way to prevent a user from inputting text using the keyboard in a textbox for VB.NET but I need the user to have the ability to scan a QR Code to input the text.

What I tried:

```
KeyPressEventArgs
e.Handled = True

KeyEventArgs
e.SuppressKeyPress = True
```

Both disable all input including scanner input

Comment: If you set up you scanner as a keyboard, it's going to be a keyboard. If you want it not to be a keyboard, refer to the manufacturer documentation on how to do that and what SDK to use.

Comment: As a note, you can always set the TextBox to `ReadOnly`, override `ProcessCmdKey` in your Form and append `(char)keydata` to the Text of the TextBox (except `Keys.Enter`, which usually comes last), only when that TextBox is the `ActiveControl`

Comment: @Jimi How would it prevent the user from doing that with a keyboard?

Comment: @GSerg Because you cannot type the content of a QR code or even a barcode in less than 100ms :) (Yes, sure, you need a StopWatch, a StringBuilder and `ShortcutsEnabled = false`, but if I mention all that, it might look like I'm answering the question instead of simply suggesting how to centralize the operation using a single, recyclable, *entry point*. A dedicated Custom Control would be better, but nobody appears to like Custom Controls anyway...)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to stop the user typing something, you just need to check that what was entered was a valid QR code in the `TextBox.Validating` event.

In the example below you will need to change `IsValidQR` function to match your particular QR codes.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
  If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    'no data entered - let the user navigate away
  ElseIf Not IsValidQR(TextBox1.Text) Then
    TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
    e.Cancel = True
  End If
End Sub

Private Function IsValidQR(expression As String) As Boolean
  Return (expression.Length = 15)
End Function
```

Comment: A few things to consider: 1) How do you validate a QR code (`expression.Length = 15` of course won't do)? 2) What if the User enters something by mistake and there are no actual means to enter a *valid* QR code? Now the User is trapped inside the TextBox and cannot do anything, not even close the Form / App 3) Setting `TextBox1.Text = String.Empty`, by the validator definition, is an invalid QR, so you cannot leave the TextBox anymore; same as before, trapped 4) What if an User enters / pastes a value that validates, but has nothing to do with a real QR? 5) ...

Comment: @Jimi, 1) The length=15 algorithm is just for the example, the OP will need to decide what constitutes a valid QR code. 2) & 3) good point, I have changed the answer to let the user navigate through the empty control 4) The contents of a QR code are not secret, so if the user knows enough to type in a valid QR code, good on them (keep in mind, the user might scan in a QR code that belongs to a different app, these need to be rejected too)

Comment: When you do that (an empty string doesn't trigger validation), then you have bypassed the validator, so you have to validate again when the data is submitted. Might as well not having a validator triggered by the `Validating` event (also setting `e.Cancel` is one of the worst things you can possibly do. An `ErrorProvider` object, for the visual notifications, should be used instead) -- The point is, you cannot allow Users to enter or paste in anything manually; if you do, any validation method can be fooled in some way, if someone knows what to enter there

Comment: While this could work the its still not ideal, for example If I have a tag number that is 1234 and I type this into the text box and click enter it will take that because it is a valid tag number but I want to remove the chance of user error so if the tag number is 1234 but the user types 1235 it will through an error. What I need is so the user only has the option to scan the QR Code to provide the tag number.

Comment: then remove the keyboard :)